# 301 Redirect with Major Changes to Path and File Name

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have an old blog website that I've recently rebuilt in Wordpress.  I'm trying to 301 redirect the old blog posts to the new Wordpress posts.

**The old URL structure:**

```
https://www.website.com/blog/phones/101/The%20Post%20Title
```

**The new URL structure:**

```
https://www.website.com/blog/The-Post-Title
```

I've tried the following code

```
Redirect 301 /blog/phones/101/The%20Post%20Title https://www.website.com/blog/The-Post-Title?
```

However, this results in redirecting me to the following page:

https://www.website.com/blog/category/cars/?/101/The%20Post%20Title

Can anyone please help me with the correct way to redirect these pages?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` like this :

```
RedirectMatch 302 /blog/phones/101/([A-Za-z]+)(?:.*?)([A-Za-z]+)(?:.*?)([A-Za-z]+) /blog/$1-$2-$3
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test .